# Thread safe code when using request scope

Tags: java, spring

I have class "`RequestContext`" which has scope `request`. This class has atribute `listOfItem`.

now I have class `MyMapper` where I need to use this list. Now when I want to `listOfItems` I always call `context.getListOfItem()` but problem is that I have a lot of private method where I need to repeat this a lot of times. It is ok when I define this atribute in constructor ? It is thread safe ?:

```
public abstract class MyMapper{

@Autowired
protected RequestContext context;

private final List<String> listOfItem;

public MyMapper() {
    this.listOfItem = context.getListOfItem(); // is this thread safe and ok ?
}

public Object map(Object entity){

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is thread safe *as long as it is declared as a prototype scope bean*, and you need to create an `init()` method that is called by Spring:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    listOfItem = context.getListOfItem();
}
```

The RequestContext is only accessible from single thread (the one allocated to handle the request), the constructor is not re-entrant by nature of the creation of the object just before it's call.

Be careful not to confuse this with the `listOfItem` somehow being safe from reentrancy problems though, just because it is locked down in the `MyMapper` object does not stop it from being shared by a getter, if one were available (there isn't in your case). I also see that it's an abstract class, but because the `listOfItem` is private, subclasses will not have access to it. Any leaked reference of that List could be manipulated by concurrent threads were there to be any copies made of the reference (since `List`s are mutable in Java).

As this safety is your intent, create a unit test that checks the visibility of the field and fails if accessing the field via reflection does not throw the appropriate exception. You may also want to comment the field with your own internal marker annotation to indicate the field is thread safe. This helps with documentation, and as an annotation, potential future automation (such as a test base that could look for all such annotations and automatically run the reflection test).

It looks very clean! Keep up the good work.

Comment: hm but isnt context null when it is autowiring ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I'll update my answer. (I've been doing Scala for the last few years...)

Comment: if the init method is called by spring, wouldn't it hit the same issue? Or are you suggesting the class shouldn't be in singleton scope?

Comment: can I use annotation @PostConstruct on init method ?

Comment: @eis: If the object were a singleton, you could only handle one request at a time.

Comment: @BrianTopping you are aware that all objects are singletons by default when using Spring?

Comment: I try it with @PostConstruct but when I call listOfItem.contains it throws NPE propably because method init is called just once when app start and all value in requestContext are null

Comment: @hudi: are you calling the Spring context to get the bean or are you using ```new()```? From a performance perspective, it's going to generally be expensive to inject the list this way, the OP was about whether it was thread safe.

Comment: parent of class MyMapper is defined in spring context and when I want to use it I just call Autowired